# Can't add item to dynamodb table with python

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I was trying to add an item to a dynamodb table, using the `boto` library. It seemed straightforward. The code I have is:

```
import boto.dynamodb

c = boto.dynamodb.connect_to_region(aws_access_key_id="xxx",
                                    aws_secret_access_key="xxx",
                                    region_name="us-west-2")

users = c.get_table("users")

users.put_item(data={'username': 'johndoe', 
                     'first_name': 'John',
                     'last_name': 'Doe'})
```

However, I get the following error:

```
'Table' object has no attribute 'put_item'
```

I think I connected to the database fine, and got the `users` table fine (the `users` variable is of the type: `boto.dynamodb.table.Table`). So, I am not sure why it can't find the put_item method (I even checked the code for the `Table` class in the `boto` library, and it has the put_item method). Any insights would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using DynamoDB v1 interface. For that use the following syntax:

```
item_data = {
    'Body': 'http://url_to_lolcat.gif',
    'SentBy': 'User A',
    'ReceivedTime': '12/9/2011 11:36:03 PM',
}

item = table.new_item(
    # Our hash key is 'forum'
    hash_key='LOLCat Forum',
    # Our range key is 'subject'
    range_key='Check this out!',
    # This has the
    attrs=item_data
)
```

Source: [An Introduction to boto’s DynamoDB interface](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb_tut.html)

I suggest to migrate to DynamoDB v2 interface: [An Introduction to boto’s DynamoDB v2 interface](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html)

```
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

table = Table('users')

users.put_item(data={'username': 'johndoe', 
                     'first_name': 'John',
                     'last_name': 'Doe'})
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thanks! Your code + item.save() did the trick. To use DynamoDB v2 Interface, do I just import import boto.dynamodb2 and do what I originally did? (btw would upvote and accept but not enough karma)

Comment: @dlaser Updated the answer with DynamoDB v2 snippet. No need to upvote, you can just accept the answer, if it works for you, to close the open loop.